# Подпись к http запросу hmac256

Tags: php, http, api, хеширование, цифровая-подпись

Не могу понять как составлять запросы, где есть подпись.
Вот основная функция, которая отправляет запросы:

```
protected function query($method, $v, $m, $params = []){

    $url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v".$v;

    $url .= '/' . $method;

    if (!empty($params)) {
        $url .= "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }

    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $url
    ]);

    $result = $client ->request($m);

    return json_decode($result->getBody());
}
```

Вот ссылка на их документацию https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

и там приводиться такой пример:

Первое действие

```
[linux]$ echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
(stdin)= c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

Второе

```
(HMAC SHA256)
[linux]$ curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A" -X POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71'
```

Я не понимаю как получается stdin и куда передавать на примере моей фунции

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно поможет функция http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто:

```
echo hash_hmac(
    'sha256',
    'symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559',
    'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j');
```

Результат:

```
c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

Я не знаю, что такое `Client` у вас, но `X-MBX-APIKEY` передается в http заголовке, `signature=c8d...` в GET-параметре.

Comment: Скопировал, вставил и у меня получился другой результат :с 
http://prntscr.com/kjw3p7

Comment: @pandal там почему то амперсанд превратился в другой символ, я исправил, сейчас должно быть ок

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне помочь разобраться с запросами на примере запроса к данным аккаунта, такая ссылка у меня получается : https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?timestamp=1534618776060&signature=6fbc3af52e9ca22235540e86e1539961e8f3ecba194297f6add803d80231fa67
401 ошибка. Для http запросов пользуюсь GuzzleHttp, $Client -его класс.
Запрос я формирую так http://prntscr.com/kk7mv7 (соре за скрины, символы ограничены). Или у меня всё верно, а ошибка только потому что я использую не свой апи, а тот который они показали в документации?

Comment: @pandal Я думаю, что оно не должно работать с теми ключами, которые указаны в примерах. Вы должны пробовать с правильными ключами.

Comment: И правда, с моими ключами ошибок нет, спасибо вам